# Continuous and Discrete random variable distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a very basic question in probability. It pertains to the difference between a continuous random variable distribution function and a discrete one. This question has confused me many times.

Suppose the continuous r.v. distribution is given by $F_X(x)$.
Then as $F_X$ is having both right and left continuity, I can say that

(i) $P(a \leq X \leq b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$

(ii) $P(a < X \leq b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$

(iii) $P(a \leq X < b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$

(iv) $P(a < X < b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$

Eqn. (i) to (iv) holds simply because $F_X$ is continuous. However how to compute these probabilities in the discrete case has always confused me.

Suppose the discrete r.v. distribution is given by $F_X(x)$.
Then as $F_X$ is **ONLY** having right continuity, I can say that

(i) $P(a \leq X \leq b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a) + P(X==a)$

(ii) $P(a < X \leq b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$

(iii) $P(a \leq X < b)=???$

(iv) $P(a < X < b)=???$

Please don't down vote just because it's easy. If an answer exists do point it out to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDF of a discrete random variable $X$ is continuous everywhere *except* at those discrete points $x_i$ for which $P\{X=x_i\} > 0$. At these points of discontinuity, the limit from the right exists as does the limit from the left, but these two limits have different values.

Let $F_X(a^{-}) = \lim_{x\uparrow a} F_X(x)$ denote the limiting value of $F_X(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left (or from below)
and let $F_X(a^+)= \lim_{x\uparrow a} F_X(x)$ denote the limit of $F_X(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right (or from above).

- If $F_X(x)$ is *continuous* at $x=a$, then $F_X(a^-)=F_X(a^+)$ and the value of $F_X(a)$ is this limit. It does not matter whether we call it the 
  limit from the right or the limit from the left, but for consistency with other
  cases, it is convenient to insist that $F_X(a)$ is the limiting value
  of $F_X(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the right: $F_X(a) = F_X(a^+)$
- As you correctly state, the value of $F_X(x)$ at $x=a$ is defined to
  be $F_X(a^+)$. **If** $F_X(x)$ is *discontinuous* at $x=a$, then since $F_X(x)$
  is a *nondecreasing* function, we have that $F_X(a^+) > F_X(a^-)$
  and the *difference* $F_X(a^+) - F_X(a^-)$ is the value of $P\{X=a\}$.
  That is,
  $$\text{For each real number}~ a, P\{X=a\} = F_X(a^+) - F_X(a^-). \tag{1}$$ 
  Note that this result is applicable to continuous random variables
  as well and leads to the conclusion that $P\{X=a\} = 0$ for every
  real number $a$: a statement that confuses many beginners in probability
  theory.

If you like this *notation* and decide that you will use it, then note
that your four probabilities differ only in whether $P\{X=a\}$ and
$P\{X=b\}$ are included in the probability of interest. For example,
your

(i) $P\{a \leq X \leq b\} = P\{a < X \leq b\} + P\{X = a\} = [F_X(b)-F_X(a)] + P\{X=a\}$
can be expressed via $(1)$ as 
$$P\{a \leq X \leq b\} = F_X(b) - F_X(a^-) = F_X(b^+)-F_X(a^-)$$
and similarly for the other cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with a discrete random variable, the probability of X being lower than b equals the probability of X being equal to or lower than the number before b.

Imagine we're working with a fair dice:

$P(2\leq X < 5) = P(2\leq X \leq 4)$. Sounds quite fair, doesn't it?

I think you can answer your question yourself now :)